# sendmail not sending

Tags: sendmail

my sendmail is not sending to AOL emails

Here is the message I get

```
Jan  4 19:18:40 doonsroom sm-mta[10961]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mailin-04.mx.aol.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jan  4 19:18:40 doonsroom sm-mta[10961]: s04FIdlJ010959: to=<email@aol.co.uk>, ctladdr=<www-data@doonsroom> (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120558, relay=mailin-04.mx.aol.com. [64.12.91.196], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Jan  4 19:18:40 doonsroom sm-mta[10961]: s04FIdlJ010959: s04FIelJ010961: DSN: Service unavailable
```

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at bounce email generated by your sendmail

**OR**

As user `root` send a test message with SMTP session tracking:

```
#!/bin/sh
RECIPIENT=email@aol.co.uk
SENDER=jd@example.net
/usr/sbin/sendmail -Am -i -v -f$SENDER -- $RECIPIENT <<END
To: $RECIPIENT
From: $SENDER
Subject: test!

test!
END
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Sorry I am not familiar with sendmail. Is this with ssmtp ?

Comment: Sendmail will try to convert unencrypted SMTP connection into encrypted one using STARTTLS command.

Comment: Okay thank you, im sorry I do not know where to find the bounce mail

Comment: It should be send back to sender. Search for the log entry with `s04FIdlJ010959` and '`from=...` to get sender email address.